# React native Google Signin Fail When i will build release apk

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I will signin with google it's working but whenever I'll create release build it not working

```
GoogleErrorcode : DEVELOPERERROR
```

Comment: if you want to google signin without firebase then read this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63846746/how-to-setup-google-sign-in-for-react-native-app-without-firebase/72041076#72041076)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by adding release keystore SHA-1  to firebase console.

Use below command to create release SHA-1 and Add it to firebase console:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

Note : Apk not need to create again.

Comment: It's working but the when i create release build then still get error code 10

Comment: what we need to add in place of keystore_name and alias name?

Answer (score 6):

Please check if Google Play App Signing is enabled from the Google Play Console -> Release Management -> App Signing.
Please try below steps:

```
1] You have to copy the SHA1 from the 'App signing certificate' section and need to add it to the Firebase projects general settings section.
2] Afterward need to regenerate the json file and add it to the project.
3] Re-generate the apk and the error will get resolved.
```

Comment: If you are passing webClientId in configuration object to GoogleSignin.configure() make sure it's correct. You can get your webClientId from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials. They're listed under "OAuth 2.0 client IDs".

Comment: I could not find Release Management -> App Signing on my google developer console

Comment: This is a great detail that is not explained in any documentation.

Comment: The app signing key is in setup > App Integrity > App signing

Answer (score 4):

If folks are still having this issue and have stumbled across this as i did. Here's what i figured out for my **react native android firebase project**

**THERE ARE MULTIPLE SHA-1's TO ADD IN FIREBASE**

**1. SHA-1 For Release Variant**

This is found in the Keystore file. You would have to add it to your *Firebase Console Project Settings*

a. Get release variant SHA-1 by running command below from you RN project root

```
$ cd android && ./gradlew signingReport
```

b. Add the release SHA-1 from here to your *Firebase Console Project Settings*

---

**2.SHA-1 After you upload to google play store for testing / prod rollout**

a .SHA-1 is found in the left nav of your google playstore console.
Setup -> App signing -> App signing key certificate

b. Add this to your *Firebase Console Project Settings*
for google sign in to work in testing / prod

Comment: sorry... it did work for me tho.. do make sure you pick the right SHA-1 from console

Comment: it worked!!! google play store app signing key needs to be added to firebase if signing by google is enabled.

Comment: Thankyou so much you saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday same problem occurred to me.

Google has released a new signing service in playstore publish console in which google will signin your app with his keystore. After signing , it will give you a new SHA which you have to add in your firebase account.

see the image for the better understanding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nLeY.png)

Comment: please provide the website link

Answer (score 1):

I have got a solution to this problem.
You have to put both SHA key i.e. SHA for debug Keystore file and SHA for release jks file, into the firebase project setting.

- Go to: https://console.firebase.google.com/
- Now choose your project
- Click the setting button near Project Overview
- Choose Project Setting
- Enter both SHA1 (debug SHA1 and release SHA1) in SHA certificate fingerprint
- Save it
- Download the google-services.json file
- Run npx react-native run-android --variant=release in terminal

It worked for me very well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new signing service from Google in the Playstore publish console, in which Google will sign your app with his keystore. After signing, it will give you a new SHA, which you need to connect to your Firebase account.

Go to Google play store ->
Release -> Setup -> App Integrity

Copy: SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from "App signing key certificate"

Add this into Firebase Project
Project Setting -> Select your app -> Add Fingerprints and Paste it here

Answer (score 0):

After than many time trying i got the solution.

In GoogleSignin.configure i was place android client it, that why i getting the error

Finally i will place the web client id([Here](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials))

```
GoogleSignin.configure({
  iosClientId: 'client ID',
  webClientId: 'My Web client ID'
})
```