# React Native google-signin working fine in dev mode but in release apk, this is not working

Tags: react-native, google-signin

I have used this flag too **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**  in my **AndroidManifest.xml** file but still not working,

Comment: You have to add your .keystore sha-1 to firebase console. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51613254/11090321

Comment: i am not using firebase, i am using it without firebase